# How do I leave a community in G+?

Tags: google-plus-communities

To join a community on Google+ I simply have to click "Join Community" at the top of the community page.

However, once joined, I can't see how to leave.

How can I leave a community I have joined on Google+?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The **Leave community** option is available under the gear in the upper left of the community's page, right above the logo for the community.

[image: Gear menu]

Comment: Note that you have to do the above (Leave community example) in Google Chrome browser. Communities is currently broken in Firefox (ver 22 at any rate) - you can't click on your community directly, and the gear symbol is greyed out.

Comment: It works for me (Firefox 22 Windows 7).

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint - maybe it's just Linux that's broken with FF...

Comment: Well, either way, this really isn't an answer to the question. At best, it's a comment on the other answer.

Comment: And if I could add a comment to the original question I would have done...but I wanted FF users to know why this might not work. (Note that I have just 1 point, and under this rather silly system that means I can submit answers but not add comments (except to my own answers))

Comment: Doesn't work in Google Chrome. It asks you to assign your membership to someone else...weird!

Comment: Today is 2017, and it seems that you can no longer be able to unfollow a community, only leave it.